# Use of parentheses with a block argument in grep produces unexpected outcome

Tags: perl

The first print of the following code does not print the expected result although the subroutine is passed as the block argument. It is expected to print 1 but print's 2. What is the difference between the first and second print statements?

```
my @arr = ("hello", "world");
print scalar(grep (sub {return "hello" eq $_}, @arr)); # return 2, not expected

print scalar(grep {"hello" eq $_} @arr); # return 1 as expected
```

Comment: I don't believe anyone has ever said these two are equivalent for grep. The sub codeword creates a code reference, but you're not evaluating the sub code. As near as I can tell, its just being used as the stringified value. Which is to say that it evaluates to "true" for all iterations of grep.

Comment: @TLP: Code refs and refs in general are always true, yes. But it's certainly not stringified. Probably numified, since it's a Boolean context ( a special case of Scalar context), but these are technicalities.

Comment: even no numification:  ["The Boolean context is just a special kind of scalar context where no conversion to a string or a number is ever performed."](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata#Scalar-values)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perl's syntax for its "functions" that take a block argument is a bit weird, and it's one of my Perl annoyances. There are some things that are just weird because that's how Perl does it:

```
grep {...} @array;   # no comma, block argument

grep $_ == 4, @array # comma, expression argument
```

Adding the `sub` doesn't look like a block argument to Perl simply because that's not the way that Perl parses things:

```
grep sub { $_ == 4} @array # missing comma, expression argument, compilation error

grep sub { $_ == 4} @array # comma, expression argument
```

But this works when you use this special block form with the `sub` left off, and Perl knows how to parse these special cases because Perl knows how to parse these special cases:

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -e 'my @f = grep { $_ == 4 } @array'
my(@f) = grep({$_ == 4;} @array);
-e syntax OK

$ perl -MO=Deparse -e 'my @f = grep $_ == 4, @array'
my(@f) = grep(($_ == 4), @array);
-e syntax OK

$ perl -MO=Deparse -e 'my @f = grep sub{$_ == 4}, @array'
my(@f) = grep(sub {
    $_ == 4;
}
, @array);
-e syntax OK

$ perl -MO=Deparse -e 'my @f = grep sub{$_ == 4} @array'
Array found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "} @array"
    (Missing operator before  @array?)
syntax error at -e line 1, near "} @array
"
-e had compilation errors.
```

That's just how it is. I wish Perl had a more general idea of anonymous functions, and that's one of the things that Raku addressed. I think Ruby did a nice job with optional blocks, too.

Now, let's make our own function, `f` with a block argument by using prototypes (which is more often than not a the best idea). The situation is slightly different (maddening, I know) for a user-defined function than Perl's builtin stuff:

Give `f` a block, no problem:

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -e 'sub f (&) { $_[0]->() }; print f {137}'
sub f (&) {
    $_[0]->();
}
print f(sub {
    137;
}
);
-e syntax OK
```

Give `f` a anonymous `sub`, no problem:

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -e 'sub f (&) { $_[0]->() }; print f sub {137}'
sub f (&) {
    $_[0]->();
}
print f(sub {
    137;
}
);
-e syntax OK
```

But, use parens and Perl thinks the block is an anonymous hash, even if you try to trick Perl into seeing it as a code block:

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -e 'sub f (&) { $_[0]->() }; print f({137})'
Type of arg 1 to main::f must be block or sub {} (not anonymous hash ({})) at -e line 1, near "})
"
-e had compilation errors.
sub f (&) {
    $_[0]->();
}
print &f({137});

$ perl -MO=Deparse -e 'sub f (&) { $_[0]->() }; print f({137;})'
syntax error at -e line 1, near ";}"
-e had compilation errors.
sub f (&) {
    $_[0]->();
}

$ perl -MO=Deparse -e 'sub f (&) { $_[0]->() }; print f({return 137})'
Type of arg 1 to main::f must be block or sub {} (not anonymous hash ({})) at -e line 1, near "})
"
-e had compilation errors.
sub f (&) {
    $_[0]->();
}
print &f({(return 137)});
```

And sometimes that's just the way it is.

Answer (score 8):

[`grep`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep) takes either a `BLOCK` or an `EXPR`.

In your second (working) formulation, you're providing a block, which evaluates with the local `$_` value as expected.

In your first formulation, you're providing an expression. The expression happens to be an anonymous subroutine with `$_` bound in it for each element being grepped, but *the subroutine itself is not evaluated*.

You can see what's going on more clearly if you were to `map` rather than `grep` the input list:

```perl
> print "[", join(",", map (sub {return "hello" eq $_}, @arr)), "]\n";
[CODE(0x14d82bdc8),CODE(0x14d82bdc8)]

> print "[", join(",", map {"hello" eq $_} @arr), "]\n";
[1,]
```

You could of course evaluate the ephemeral subroutine as part of the grep expression, but the syntax gets very beautiful very quickly:

```perl
print scalar(grep ((sub {return "hello" eq $_})->(), @arr)); # returns 1
```

Comment: For completeness, if the OP wanted to use a predefined function as EXPR he could also write `grep foo(), LIST` or `grep {foo()} LIST`  or `grep $code_ref->(), LIST`  ... and so on

Answer (score 4):

`grep` doesn't take a subroutine. In fact, it's not even a real function<sup>[1]</sup>. [`grep`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep) can be called in one of two ways, and they really only differ syntactically: With an explicit block, or with an expression argument.

```
grep {"hello" eq $_} @arr;
grep("hello" eq $_, @arr);
```

You've already figured out the first form. For the second one, the expression you pass as the first "argument" to `grep` gets evaluated, not only once, but once per element of the array.

```
print scalar(grep (sub {return "hello" eq $_}, @arr));
```

In the example you gave, the expression argument is `sub { return "hello" eq $_ }`. That expression will get evaluated (the expression itself with be evaluated; I did *not* say the subroutine will get called. The subroutine will never get called) once per list element. `grep` returns any elements for which the block returns true, and "true" is defined by [Scalar values](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata#Scalar-values):

> A scalar value is interpreted as FALSE in the Boolean sense if it is undefined, the null string or the number 0 (or its string equivalent, "0"), and TRUE if it is anything else.

And a subroutine is not undefined, the null string, or the number zero, so a subroutine is a true value. Hence, every element of the input list satisfies the (trivial) block.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Many of the built-in Perl functions in the confusingly-named [functions page](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions) are not real functions and are in fact language keywords. [`sort`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort) is an infamous example. There is *no way* to write a function in pure Perl that behaves like `sort` (in that it can take a block, a subroutine name, or neither).

Comment: Re "*Many of the built-in Perl functions in the confusingly-named functions page are not real functions*", Actually, none of the functions in perlfunc are <strike>functions</strike>subroutines. They're all operators. This is listed right at the top of the page: "*The functions in this section can serve as terms in an expression. They fall into two major categories: list operators and named unary operators.*" (Technically, there's also at least one nullary operator.)

Comment: Re _"There is no way to write a function in pure Perl that behaves like `sort`"_ Well this is true for all built-ins with no `prototype` -  like `sort` - because their special syntax needs special parsing. But the rest -and there are many- [can actually be overridden with "real" functions](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub#Overriding-Built-in-Functions). But I fail to see how this is relevant here with `grep` not accepting a code-ref. Some 
 other languages have such a  "lambda" interface, Perl has a different one. That's semantic, not syntax.